# Which uses less memory? A View Controller with 5 buttons, or a View Controller with a tableview with 5 items?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

might be a dumb question, but im trying to keep my mobile app as small and less load heavy as possible. wondering if a view with 5 buttons uses more or less memory or processing power than a view with a tableview that has 5 tableview items / cells? could be a dumb question, im not sure

[image]

Comment: Try both and see what results you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that 5 buttons is all you need - you can use buttons with separate outlets or even put all of them in single outlet collection.
Also in order to compare memory and CPU usage you can build your app and open Xcode Debug Navigator.

[image]